# Диффи-Хеллман 64 открытый ключ для 128битного шифрования

Tags: c#

Помогите пожалуйста!

используя `System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellmanCng` создать открытый ключ для 128 битного закрытого ключа. Мой код

```
ECDiffieHellman m_ECDiffieHellman = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(128);
List<byte> publicKey = m_ECDiffieHellman.PublicKey.ToByteArray().ToList();
```

Сваливается в исключение

`Необработанное исключение типа "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" в PresentationFramework.dll`

подозреваю, что конструктор не принимает размер 128 бит, вопрос как быть тогда?

Инструкция к устройству ниже 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Документацию читать нужно для этой перегрузки конструктора. Допустимая длина ключа: 256, 384 и 521 бит.

Comment: Ищите стороннюю реализацию: Chilkat, BouncyCastle и т.д.